# How do I modify proxy responses using asynchronous servlets?

Tags: asynchronous, jetty, servlet-3.0, ssi

I'm trying to implement an asynchronous servlet, that will receive an end user's request, pass it on to a backend server and grab the response.

So far, this sounds like a pretty standard application of Jetty's `ProxyServlet`.

Now, the twist is that my backend will respond with include statements (kind of like Server-Side-Includes), which I need to parse, query the backend for and insert at the appropriate place in the end user's response stream.

How would you go about implementing this? I'm specifically curious about parsing and firing off the intermediate requests during the `onResponseContent` callback, which I understand may or may not contain a full response (and thus may only contain parts of the include statement).

To illustrate, here's what I currently have:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet",
        urlPatterns = {"/my/outbounduri/*"},
        initParams = {
                @WebInitParam(name = "proxyTo", value = "/servlet/backend")
        }
)
public class MyHandler extends ProxyServlet {
    @Override
    protected void customizeProxyRequest(HttpServletRequest srequest, 
            HttpServletResponse sresponse ) {
        // add custom headers for the backend
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResponseContent(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, Response proxyResponse, 
            byte[] buffer, int offset, int length, Callback callback) {
        try {
            // instead of passing the content on, we need to catch 
            // include statements
            // response.getOutputStream().write(buffer, offset, length);
            callback.succeeded();
        } catch (Throwable x) {
            callback.failed(x);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResponseSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, Response proxyResponse) {
        AsyncContext asyncContext = request.getAsyncContext();
        asyncContext.complete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are modifying content during the proxying of that content, then use Jetty 10.x (or newer) and its [`org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.AsyncMiddleManServlet`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AsyncMiddleManServlet.html).

*Note: this is brand new functionality, and there is bound to be some warts in the implementation.*

This is a specialized `AsyncProxyServlet` designed to ease the complexities of modifying the request content from the client and/or the response content from the remote server.  (This is especially complicated when the 2 sides of the proxy have different Transfer-Encoding)

In your use case, start with overriding `AsyncMiddleManServlet.newServerResponseContentTransformer(HttpServletRequest clientRequest, HttpServletResponse proxyResponse, Response serverResponse)` and have it return a new instance of a `ContentTransformer` of your design that does the logic you need for this transformation.

Implement your own [`ContentTransformer`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AsyncMiddleManServlet.ContentTransformer.html) which does what it needs to do in the `.transform(ByteBuffer input, boolean finished, List<ByteBuffer> output)`

Read what you can from `input`, once you have something to write, do a `output.add(modified)`.  Pay attention to the `finished` flag, as that lets you know when the last bit of input content has been received.

Of other note, if you need to control the differences in the URL from the client request side, to the remote server side, override the `String rewriteTarget(HttpServletRequest clientRequest)` method, reading the client request information and returning a modified remote URL string.

Comment: Awesome response! Now, if there's a way to transform input based on the backend response headers, I'm all set.

Comment: @mabi you need to be clear on what you mean by "input". If you mean "a way to transform the server response content based on the server response header", then that is certainly possible. When you create your server response transformer, you have the server response (with headers and all) available, so you can look at the server response headers while you're transforming the server response content.

Comment: I missed the fact that the response is available to the transformer. Yes, that's what I'm after. Keeps getting better and better, thanks!